# oracle cat index throws invalid sql name exception

Tags: oracle, full-text-indexing

We recently upgraded our database to Oracle 12c and since then it throws `ORA-44003: invalid sql name` exception while inserting on a table which has cat index.

We only have cat index on one column, which was working fine with Oracle 11g.

The interesting part is, i can insert the same record if i keep trying. Sometimes on the second, sometimes on the tenth try.

Here is the exception:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-44003: invalid SQL name
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 479 
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRVDML", line 415
ORA-06512: at "EMISDB.DR$IDX_AML_NOTICE_DESCTC", line 1
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SONARDB.DR$IDX_NOTICE_DESCTC'
```

I dropped and created the cat index with the script:

```
create index IDX_NOTICE_DESC on NOTICE (DESCRIPTION) indextype is ctxsys.ctxcat
```

I would appreciate any tip.

Comment: i read the documentation but i don't know what to verify. It is a simple string.

Comment: as per the doc : ORA-44003: invalid SQL name Cause: The input parameter string was not a valid simple SQL name. Action: Check with the DBMS_ASSERT spec to verify that the parameter string is a valid simple SQL name. also check this site https://community.oracle.com/thread/2132941 hope it will help you, please check the last url i added please

Comment: I could not find the project from the link. I guess it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I would recommend you to check the code around the line 415 in the "CTXSYS.DRVDML". You can use http://www.codecrete.net/UnwrapIt in order to unwrap it. If you can't unwrap it post here a wrapped version - i'll try to unwrap it.

Comment: Is the trigger `SONARDB.DR$IDX_NOTICE_DESC`  or `SONARDB.DR$IDX_NOTICE_DESC` auto-generated?  Could be that 12c  (or whatever is generating the trigger is generating an invalid name.  I would try naming the index something very short, perhaps `IDX_NTC_DSC`

Comment: Did you upgrade go smooth, or were there any errors ?
Check product upgrade status for oracle text:  select  comp_name,  version, status  from  dba_registry;